# jump from nested stacks to one screen in root in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i have below roots in my react native project using react navigation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2gd.jpg

main is a bottomTabNavigator with 3 screens and in the Profile Screen i have a 3 screen topTabNavigator.
in the EditProfile screen i have a log out button. when i press the log out button i want to navigate to Login screen . please help me reach this out

Comment: It would be great if you could post the code for your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

i found it by my self
in the Profile screen i used screenProps just like this:

```js
class Profile extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1,}}>        
            <AppNavigator screenProps={{ rootNavigation: this.props.navigation }}/>
             </View>
        )
    }
}
```

and in the EditProfile page when user touches logout button i run this code:

```js
this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation.navigate('login')
```